# How to exit infinite navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

Let me explain the problem with an example; Let's say I went to the relevant page by pressing the Sign in text, and from there I went to the relevant page by pressing the sign up text. Since the GetOfAll method is used on the SignIn page, it does not show me this page. However, if I press the sign in and sign up texts a few times and start pressing the back button on the phone, it shows me the SignUp page several times. After that, it goes to the Onboarding page, which is located before arriving at the SignUp page. But what I'm trying to do is to click back once on the SignIn page and get to the signUp page. If he presses the back button one more time, he will come to the onBoarding page. No matter how many times I press the Sign in or Sign up text, this route always occurs. The maximum route should be as follows;

**Onboarding > SignUp(with the help of text) > SignIn(with the help of text) >SignUp(when the Back key is pressed) > Onboarding**

```
RichTextWidget(
                  text: 'Do you already have an account? ',
                  span: 'Sign in',
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      Get.to(
                        const SignIn(),
                        transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      );
                    },
                )
```

This is the part of my Sign Up page that redirects to the SignIn page.

```
RichTextWidget(
                text: 'Don't have a registered account? ',
                span: 'Sign up',
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () {
                    Get.off(const SignUp(),
                        transition: Transition.leftToRight,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                  },
              )
```

This is a part of the SignIn page that allows redirection to the SignUp page.

Comment: Just use `Get.back()` on press `Signup` in `Sign In` page

Comment: Sign in and Sign up are two pages you don't want to go back to once you leave them. You better use `Get.offAll()`. And if you redirect the user to Sign in page because he has to log in, you should use `Get.offAll()` too.